# Change Windows 10 MAC Address on a MacBook Pro using BootCamp

Tags: boot-camp, broadcom

I have Windows 10 Home installed on my Mid 2015 15' MacBook Pro.  It has the broadcom wifi card.

When I change the driver properties, more specifically the Locally Administered MAC, the actual address never changes even after disable/enable the network device and hard reset.  When I reboot and goto the driver properties again, the newly entered MAC is retained in the Locally Administered MAC field.

Just to double check, I looked in the registry keys for the network adapter and saw the custom MAC was present for the network address key.

What can I do to fix this as my network requires me to change my MAC.

FYI, I am able to change my MAC when booted into OSx using terminal.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/320721/6-apple-wallet-features-you-may-not-have-known-about/

Comment: you ever figure this out? I'm having the same exact issue